# mysqldump lost referential action subclause of foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql

After dump with

```
mysqldump --no-data -h localhost -u root -p my_db | sed 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*//g' > $DEST_FILE
```

part of the foreign key constraints lost like this:

ORIGIN:

```
  CONSTRAINT `fk_owner_id_app_group` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `app_user` (`app_user_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```

AFTER:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_owner_id_app_group` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `app_user` (`app_user_id`)
```

The `ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT` part lost.
No error or warning issued during exporting.
Checked mysqldump manual, didn't find any related options. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html
Have anyone experienced this? Is this a mysqldump bug?

The environment here is.
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64)
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is, that it's omitted because it's the default anyway.

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> - RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table. Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON DELETE or ON UPDATE clause.
>
> For an ON DELETE or ON UPDATE that is not specified, the default action is always RESTRICT.

Comment: That explains. But if the server has a default setting rather than RESTRICT, would the server does unexpected behavior, like CASCADE?

Comment: There's no way to change the default and the mysql developers also won't do that. This behaviour is the standard as defined in the ANSI SQL'92 standard. You don't have to worry about that.